# 409 response when uploading to artifactory using X-Checksum-Sha1 header with Apache's HTTP client in Java

Tags: java, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I am writing a Jenkins plugin in Java that uses the Apache HttpClient (org.apache.http.client.HttpClient) to upload artifacts to JFrog Artifactory. As part of the process I would like to add a checksum to the artifacts that I upload.

From what I understand, this can be done using the X-Checksum headers and calculating the checksum locally. However, when I try to do this, the artifactory server gives me the following response:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 409,
    "message" : "Checksum policy 'LocalRepoChecksumPolicy: CLIENT' rejected the
                 artifact 'bluemix-ace-maven-local:test_build/4/log.txt'. Checksums info
                 ChecksumsInfo{
                   checksums={
                     SHA-1=ChecksumInfo{
                       type=SHA-1,
                       original='1a5bc1ae3c47e519f8bd69f90802c9fcf9fbddb3',
                       actual='c4c9da01b9e278d68a4c15bb95e41437799700ed'
                     },
                     MD5=ChecksumInfo{
                       type=MD5,
                       original='null',
                       actual='aa4023acbcb095cceb35ac82f9a913a8'
                     },
                     SHA-256=ChecksumInfo{
                       type=SHA-256,
                       original='null',
                       actual='5032a081754db0ce3f8b394a5215940e30456a77ea1e82765ceb595c8e0050da'
                     }
                   }
                }"
  } ]
}
```

The checksum I am calculating locally is 1a5bc1ae3c47e519f8bd69f90802c9fcf9fbddb3

I have verified by going into bash and doing a shasum on that file. It matches the above. So for some reason artifactory is calculating a different sha1 sum than the one I have locally. Why might this be?

This issue seems to be very similar:
https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-8553

But his solution didn't help me. I have also tried MD5 and SHA256.

Comment: You might want to show some details here: use a silly file like `test.txt` with content `test`: show the code you're using the calculate the SHA1 for that, and show the response you get for sending that file up to JFrog Artifacts, and also explain (and ideally, link to) where in the JFrog docs you found the description for how checksums should be both computed, and sent over.

Comment: Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46914787/740553, which is an answer for Java (not C# as the question) that relies on using the official JFrog library (https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java), which seems a much better approach than to roll your own communication using Apache's HttpClient.

Comment: The problem turned out to be the fact that I was using a multipart entity which adds headers, etc. to the uploaded file

Comment: Also my reason for not using the artifactory java client is because it only allowed me to authenticate using username and password. It didn't allow me to authenticate using API key.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out this problem myself. The problem was that I was using a multipart entity in Java, which means that headers, etc. are added to the uploaded file, which would cause the checksum to be different. I switched to BufferedHttpEntity and now it is working.

Comment: Note that if you solve your own problem within an hour of posting it, then really your question just needed that push for you to look harder, and is probably better deleted again, _unless_ you want to write up a detailed answer that explains what was wrong, because of what code, and how it got fixed, with code changes to show how others can implement the same fix.

Comment: I had been struggling with this issue for more than a week, which is why I preemptively posted this before going to work on it again, so that I wasn't banging my head against a wall. There have been many times when I would google a problem and find a solution like this one, and benefit from it. So I don't think I am harming anyone by leaving it up.

Comment: this isn't about "harm", this is about "does it benefit": the whole point of SO is to have questions with real answers, for the benefit of all future visitors with the same problem as you. If you solved this problem: either write up a detailed explanation that others can use too, or delete your question because it'll just frustrate future visitors when they find a questions with an answer that doesn't explain how to solve the problem: that's not an answer, and so that'd be plain not following SO policies for writing questions and answers.